# does weight re-calculate when one of the children view changes its visibility to gone in run time code?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, visibility, android-layout-weight

I have a linear layout with two linear layout as children.

they have weights. sometimes that lower linera layout child is with visibility `gone` but then i would expect the upper child to  be vertically centered

Which didn't happen.

Why is that?

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@color/google_blue900"
        android:orientation="vertical">
      <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/display_name_layout"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          android:background="@color/google_red100"
          android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/account_display_name"
            style="@style/AccountDataDisplayName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/google_green50"
            tools:text="DisplayNameIsLongSoItShouldBeTruncatedAtSomePoint"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/display_name_chevron"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/account_menu_chevron_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/account_menu_chevron_size"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/account_menu_chevron_top_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/account_menu_chevron_left_margin"/>
      </LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/account_name_layout"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          android:background="@color/google_blue50"
          android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/account_name"
            style="@style/AccountDataAccountName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@color/google_yellow50"
            tools:text="emailisverylongaswellwewantittogettruncated@gmail.longdomain.com"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/account_name_chevron"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/account_menu_chevron_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/account_menu_chevron_size"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/account_menu_chevron_top_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/account_menu_chevron_left_margin"/>
      </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

when i change the visibility of the second linear layout to be gone,

I expect the upper linear layout to be center vertical in it's linear layout parent.

what am i missing as now it's not centered vertically

[image]

Comment: Does not it fill the screen height?

Comment: @PankajKumar as you can see in the screenshot - the blue is the parten linear layout, so the upper chile doesn't span in height. but i don;t care i just want it to be centered vertically

Comment: In that case you need to use android:layout_weight=".5" for both layouts, If I understood your question. If not, then please add a sketch about the expectation

Answer (score 1):

LL always places it children starting top left.
So 
no meaning to vertical center when LL vertical
no meaning to horizontal center when LL horizontal